# Excel crippled by block of complex array formulas almost undeletable

Tags: excel

Large (~300mb) .xlsm project ridiculously slow for months (½ hour just to load). Finally tracked it down I think to somehow a complex array formula referencing several sheets mistakenly copied into 200,000+ cells. Now even trying to delete or clear those cells makes Excel not responding anymore.

Clearing the cells one at a time works but Excel takes over a minute to respond to further input after the delete key is pressed to clear just one cell. So desperatly I wrote a tiny macro to clear them one at a time and let it run all night, but it deleted only ~200 cells... at this rate will take 1000+ days.

Apparently problem has existed for awhile so it’s present in all backups anywhere near useful. Offending sheet has too many links to other sheets in the file to try to separate/copy/reproduce it. Flailing about trying stuff: safe mode, but it didn't help. Anyone has another idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Did you try turning off the automatic calculatons before running the code?

Comment: Thanks but yes. Further, it's puzzling why deleting even a single cell takes so long, because the number of cells dependent on the cells I'm trying to clear is ZERO.

Comment: Then there is a good chance you have volatile functions like Indirect,Address,Offset...

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issue in the past where correcting the broken sheet was almost impossible. I was able to "repair" it by creating a new sheet and copying the data in the new sheet.

these steps explain how I did it without breaking formulas and format.

1. In excel, press Ctrl-tilde (tilde is above tab: ~) to show the formula or values of every cell.
2. Copy ranges in your sheets and paste in a notepad. You could copy/paste whole sheets but I undestand that you are trying to remove some of the rows/columns  .
3. Copy what was pasted into notepad and paste it in the new sheet. 
   this will remove any link to the broken excel sheet. 
   (will paste `=A1` instead of `='C:\Users\name\Desktop\filename.xlsm]Sheet7'!$A$1`)
4. Select whole sheet of broken file and use the format painter to apply broken sheet's format to the new sheet (format Painter works between excel sheets)

Do this for each of the sheets in your workbook and it should be repaired.
It might take some time to repair it but once it is done, you will save time whenever you will be using your file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.
Yes the workbook has volatiles, quick test hinted they clearly were making it worse but not the whole issue.
Days trying all suggestions here and others including throwing more physical memory at it (still thrashed).
"Solution", if one can call it that with a straight face, was delete the entire offending tab/sheet, painfully recreate it.
Ctrl-tilde an excellent suggestion (although the lower-case flavor (Ctrl-`) actually was what worked).
Horrible side effect, reason unknown, the entire VBA project and the sheet's link to VBA vanished. Restored code from backup, recreated link, but perhaps a clue.
Still the book is big and slow but now works with only limited visits to Not Responding land. Thanks again.